# What's the lifetime of the parameter of a coroutine

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, coroutine

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/coroutine>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
struct InitialSuspend{
    bool await_ready(){
        return false;
    }
    bool await_suspend(std::experimental::coroutine_handle<> h){
          return false;
    }
    void await_resume(){
        
    }
};
struct FinalSuspend{
    bool await_ready() noexcept{
        return false;
    }
    void await_suspend(std::experimental::coroutine_handle<> h) noexcept{
       std::cout<<"FinalSuspend await_suspend\n";
    }
    std::string await_resume() noexcept{
        std::cout<< "await_resume for FinalSuspend\n";
       return "await_resume for FinalSuspend\n";
    }
};
struct Task{
    struct promise_type;
    using coroutine_type = std::experimental::coroutine_handle<promise_type>;
    struct promise_type{
        auto initial_suspend(){
           return InitialSuspend{};
        }
        void unhandled_exception(){
            std::cout<<"unhandled_exception\n";
            std::terminate();
        }
        auto final_suspend() noexcept{
           return FinalSuspend{};
        }
        // void return_value(std::string const& v){
        //    value_ = v;
        // }
        void return_void(){

        }
        auto get_return_object(){
            return Task{coroutine_type::from_promise(*this)};
        }
        std::string value_;
    };
    coroutine_type handler_;
};
struct AwaitAble{
    bool await_ready(){
        return false;
    }
    void await_suspend(std::experimental::coroutine_handle<> h){
        std::cout<<"await_suspend\n";
    }
    std::string await_resume(){
       std::cout<<"await_resume\n";
       return "abc";
    }
};
struct Observe0{
    Observe0(int v):id_(v){
        std::cout<< id_ <<"  constructor0\n";
    }
    ~Observe0(){
        std::cout<< id_ <<" destroy0\n";
    }
    Observe0(Observe0 const& v):id_(v.id_+1){
        std::cout<< id_<<" copy constructor0\n";
    }
    Observe0(Observe0&& v):id_(v.id_+1){
       std::cout<< id_<<" move constructor0\n";
    }
    int id_;
};
Task MyCoroutine(Observe0 p){
    auto r1 = co_await AwaitAble{};
}
int main(){
    Observe0  aa{1};  //#1
    auto r = MyCoroutine(aa); //#2
    std::cout<<"caller\n";
    r.handler_.resume();
    r.handler_.destroy();
    std::cin.get();
}
```

The [output](https://godbolt.org/z/c8Wqejxox) is:

```
1  constructor0
2 copy constructor0
3 move constructor0
await_suspend
2 destroy0
caller
await_resume
FinalSuspend await_suspend
3 destroy0
1 destroy0
```

We can observe the creation or destruction of an object by using the above code. The first print occurs at `#1`, which constructs the object `a`. The second print occurs at the initialization of the coroutine parameter at `#2`. The third print occurs at the initialization of the coroutine parameter copy, which is ruled by the following rules:
[[dcl.fct.def.coroutine#13]](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.coroutine#13)

> When a coroutine is invoked, after initializing its parameters ([expr.call]), a copy is created for each coroutine parameter. For a parameter of type cv T, the copy is a variable of type cv T with automatic storage duration that is direct-initialized from an xvalue of type T referring to the parameter.

These three objects all have their unique number which is convenient to observe the lifetime of the associated object.  According to the fifth print, the destructor is called for the **coroutine parameter** whose name is `p`. However, according to [[expr.await#5.1]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.await#5.1)

> Otherwise, control flow returns to the current coroutine caller or resumer ([dcl.fct.def.coroutine]) **without exiting any scopes** ([stmt.jump]).

It means that suspend the coroutine and transfer the control to the caller, the parameter scope of the coroutine is not considered exit. Hence, the lifetime of the parameter should not end. Why is the destructor of the parameter called after the first transferring to the caller of the coroutine? Should it be considered a bug in the compiler?

Answer (score 2):

The lifetime of a parameter is not part of the function's scope; it's part of the [*caller's* scope](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.call#7):

> The initialization and destruction of each parameter occurs within the context of the calling function.

This is the entire reason why [dcl.fct.def.coroutine#13] exists. In order for a coroutine to preserve its parameters, it has to own them. Which means it *must* copy/move them from the parameters into local automatic storage.

Comment: *The initialization and destruction of each parameter occur within the context of the calling function.* That merely means the initialization or destruction for the parameters is the responsibility of the caller. However, the precondition of the destruction of an object is the object lifetime is over. *It is implementation-defined whether the lifetime of a parameter ends when the function in which it is defined returns or at the end of the enclosing full-expression.* hints that. Suspend a coroutine seems does not mean either case.

Comment: @xmh0511: Suspending a coroutine counts as returning from a function call as far as the "calling function" is concerned. My point is that the lifetime of parameters are not controlled by the function being called. They are not part of its "scope" and therefore are not preserved by the coroutine's suspension.

Comment: The scope of parameters is function parameter scope which encloses the block scope introduced by the compound-statement of the function. Hence, the parameter is in that scope. *A destructor is invoked implicitly: for a constructed object with automatic storage duration ([basic.stc.auto]) when the block in which an object is created exits; In each case, the context of the invocation is the context of the construction of the object.* So, as you said, it does in the context of the caller. if the implementation chooses...

Comment: ... "the lifetime of a parameter ends when the function in which it is defined returns ", the suspend indeed returns to the caller as per *control flow **returns** to the current coroutine caller or resumer*. However, if it chooses the latter, I don't know how to interpret it(I mean, whether suspend the coroutine and returns counts as go into the end of the enclosing full-expression?).

Comment: @xmh0511: "*I don't know how to interpret it*" I don't know what you mean. Control flow returns to the caller, and at some point, the full-expression containing the function call will finish execution. At that point, the lifetime of the function parameters end. I don't see where being a coroutine affects this.

Comment: Ah, I got that. *Return to the caller* means that, return to the point in the full-expression that is immediately after the expression of the call. However, it's underspecified in the standard.

Comment: @xmh0511: What is "underspecified" here? "A coroutine returns to its caller or resumer (9.5.4) by the co_return statement or when suspended (7.6.2.3)." is just as well-specified as the "return" statement's specification: "A function returns to its caller by the return statement."

Comment: The underspecified here is what's the meaning of *return to the caller*. In other words, after "return to the caller", it will execute the instructions that are immediately after the `function call` instruction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230618/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-xmh0511).

Comment: _The initialization and destruction of each parameter occurs within the context of the calling function_ This means that an exception thrown from ctor/dtor won't be captured by the callee, if it has handlers. Not that the caller must destroy parameters.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer *In each case, the context of the invocation is the context of the construction of the object* [class.dtor#15](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.dtor#15) mentions that. In simple, The caller is responsible to destroy the object since it constructed the object.