# Default reference parameters and lifetimes in coroutines

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

I'm confused about the lifetime of parameters passed to C++ coroutines.
Answering to [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66897608/whats-the-lifetime-of-the-parameter-of-a-coroutine), smart people stated that

> The lifetime of a parameter is [...] part of the caller's scope

Now, to follow up, what happens when passing default arguments like

```c++
generator my_coroutine(string&& s = string()) {...}
```

So, if `my_coroutine` was a normal function, `s` would be valid throughout its scope. However, this seems to no longer hold if `my_coroutine` is a coroutine.

In particular the results of the following coroutine-test surprised me:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <coroutine>

struct Test {
    int i = 3;
    Test() { std::cout << "test constructed\n";}
    Test(const Test&) = delete;
    Test(Test&&) = delete;
    ~Test() { std::cout << "test destructed\n"; }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Test& t) { return os << t.i; }
};

template<class T>
generator<int> coro_test(T&& t = T()) {
  int i = 0;
  while(i++ < 3) co_yield i;
  if(i == t.i) co_yield 100;
}

int main () {
  auto gen = coro_test<Test>();
  while(gen.is_valid()) {
    std::cout << *gen << "\n";
    ++gen;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

results:

```
test constructed
test destructed
1
2
3
```

PS: for completeness, here's my `generator`:

```c++
template<class T>
struct generator {
  struct promise_type;
  using coro_handle = std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>;

  struct promise_type {
    T current_value;
    auto get_return_object() { return generator{coro_handle::from_promise(*this)}; }
    auto initial_suspend() const noexcept { return std::suspend_never{}; }
    auto final_suspend() const noexcept { return std::suspend_always{}; }
    void unhandled_exception() const { std::terminate(); }

    template<class Q>
    auto yield_value(Q&& value) {
      current_value = std::forward<Q>(value);
      return std::suspend_always{};
    }
  };
private:
  coro_handle coro;
  generator(coro_handle h): coro(h) {}
public:
  bool is_valid() const { return !coro.done(); }
  generator& operator++() { if(is_valid()) coro.resume(); return *this; }

  T& operator*() { return coro.promise().current_value; }
  const T& operator*() const { return coro.promise().current_value; }

  generator(const generator&) = delete;
  generator& operator=(const generator&) = delete;
  ~generator() { if(coro) coro.destroy(); }
};
```

Comment: IIRC default arguments are implemented at the call site, so it doesn't change anything. They still exist from a lifetime perspective in the expression in the caller's scope. As soon as that expression is no longer valid (e.g. you suspend) then the arguments are also no longer valid.

Comment: "*Answering to a previous question, smart people stated that*" 'Smart people' also had other words that came after those words. 'Smart people' also wrote those words in the context of a specific question, which you're ignoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in said "previous question", the first thing that happens in a coroutine is that parameters are "copied" into storage owned by the coroutine. However, the "copy" is ultimately initialized based on the type declared in the signature. That is, if a parameter is a reference, then the "copy" of that parameter is *also* a reference.

So a coroutine function that takes reference parameters is much like any kind of asynchronous function that takes reference parameters: the caller *must* ensure that the referenced object continues to exist throughout the time that the object will be used. A default parameter which initializes a reference is a circumstance that the caller *cannot* control the lifetime of (other than providing an explicit parameter).

You created an API that is inherently broken. Don't do that. Indeed, it's best to avoid passing references to async functions of any kind, but if you do, never give them default parameters.